# Positioning Canvas in relation to the title bar of the window

Tags: java, javafx

I have a graphic context:

```
gc.strokeText(String.format("%d",test), 0, 0);
```

I add this to the stage like this:

```
p.getChildren().addAll(canvas);
```

I get this result:

[image]

What can i do, or is there a way to prevent the canvas to start behind title bar?
(I can do this by setting the start position x,y, but that seems a oncomfortabel solution)

Is there a way to set the canvas just below the title bar, no matter how high this title bar is.

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please - demonstrating what _exactly_ you want to achieve and how it doesn't work.

Comment: James_D anwsered it correctly, thus my question was clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene and the canvas it contains *are* positioned immediately below the title bar. The problem is the way you have positioned the text in the canvas.

The text is positioned in the canvas according to the coordinates provided and the current values of the `GraphicsContext`'s `textAlign` property (which determines how the `x` coordinate is used) and `textBaseline` property (which determines how the `y` coordinate is used). See the "Text Attributes" section of the attributes table in the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html).

The default `textBaseline` property is `VPos.BASELINE`, which means the *baseline* of the text will be positioned with the provided y-coordinate, which is `0` in your case. Thus the text baseline will be at `0` (the top of the canvas), and most of the text (everything except any descenders) will be above the top of the canvas and not be visible.

To position the *top* of the text at the y-coordinate `0`, set the `textBaseline` to `TOP`:

```
gc.setTextBaseline(VPos.TOP);
gc.strokeText(String.format("%d",test), 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @James_D, it works like a glove!